# Sklave vs. Leibeigener

Tags: meaning, difference, noun

Wie unterscheiden sich *Sklaven* und *Leibeigene*?

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Leibeigener) wurde der Begriff des *Leibeigenen* früher verwendet. Ist das die einzige Unterscheidung?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Wikipedia-Artikel zur Leibeigenschaft https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibeigenschaft versucht ausführlich, die Unterschiede herzuleiten. Verkürzt gesagt: Die Definition des Unterschieds hängt vom Standpunkt und der Zeit ab.

Zunächst einmal wird der Begriff Leibeigenschaft vorwiegend für die Zustände im Mittelalter verwendet, während man die Situation im Altertum (antikes Griechenland, Rom) eher als Sklaverei bezeichnet. Tatsächlich kann man durchaus auch Unterschiede zwischen den beiden Konzepten finden. Während der Sklave überhaupt keine Rechte hat und nichts besitzt, kann ein Leibeigener durchaus auf eigene Kosten wirtschaften (wenngleich er einen grossen Teil davon als Leibrente abgeben muss)

Inwiefern sich die Beurteilung unterscheidet, kommt aber offenbar auf den Standpunkt an. Moderne Geschichtswissenschaft tendiert nach obigem Artikel eher Richtung Gleichstellung, da beides gleichermassen geächtet wird.

Comment: Ergänzend: Leibeigener ergibt meines Erachtens nur innerhalb des Lehenswesens Sinn, während Sklave auch außerhalb der griechisch-römischen Antike (z. B. amerikanische Südstaaten prä-Bürgerkrieg) verwendet wurde. Die Leibeigenschaft wurde im Zuge der Bauernbefreiung abgeschafft; in Russland meines Erachtens erst kurz vor der Oktoberrevolution.

Comment: @Jan: Ich würde es anders formulieren: Ich würde sagen, dass der Begriff "Leibeigener" mit dem Lehenswesen zusammenhängt. Aber man kann auch Leibeigene / Sklaven halten unabhängig vom aktuellen wirtschaftlichen Umfeld. Aus Sicht des Betroffenen ist der Unterschied wohl eher ein Euphemismus.

Comment: Nicht ganz falsch; wenn es nicht so politisch unkorrekt wäre, brächte ich jetzt noch schnell den *leNoR* … Allerdings würde ich trotzdem *Sklave* als den allgemein verwendeteren Begriff beschreiben und den *Leibeigenen* einem speziellen Kontext zuordnen wollen.

Answer (score 2):

Diese zwei Wörter geben auch auf Schwedisch (meine Muttersprache): *slav* und *livegen*.

Von was ich verstehe **gehört ein Leibeigener fest zu einem gewissen Landstück** und muss darauf arbeiten. Leibeigene können/könnten nicht verkauft werden, was mit Sklaven möglich ist/war.